# Angular Spring boot war deployment in tomcat is giving 401

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat

I know that this combination of technologies and issues have been asked a lot before but I am unable to proceed even after reading most of the related questions.

My set up involves an angular app served by a spring boot end point. All is well on the dev front with all requests being served up correctly. So I installed a local tomcat (tried 10 first and got nowhere with it, so went down to 9). The steps I did are

1. For angular dist creation

```
ng build --base-href=/audittool/
```

2. Copied dist contents into the my src/main/resources folder of spring boot project
3. Changed pom to package as war and added provided scope for tomcat, extended SpringBootServletInitializer and performed a

```
mvn clean install
```

4. Fired up manager-gui on my tomcat, deployed the created war (this has the same name as the base href used in the ng build step, audittoo)
5. War was deployed successfully

Now when I access http://localhost:8082/audittool I am getting

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
```

I have done most of the steps manually (copying dist folder) as I just wanted to test my app out on a dedicated tomcat instance.

I have read enough and more on this topic and I still do not know what I am missing.
I know that the 401 could be CORS, but the base href is supposed to solve that as long as the war deploy name matches, which it does. So why am I not even being served index.html, no static resource is being downloaded.

I have nothing special in my POM other than the usual stuff (and one WSDL that I use for auth)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>audittool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>audittool</name>
    <description>spring boot project for audit tool</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>audittool</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>com......soaplloginservice.gen</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run a postman request it goes through fine using the http://localhost:8082/audittool/
So it is only when I try to get to the angular front end that I am getting into trouble.

Any advice is most appreciated.

My SecurityConfig class is as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private WebServiceAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Autowired
    private JWTRequestFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and().
                authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate")
                .permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

My LoginController which is the first end point hit for authentication has the @CrossOrigin annotation. At least up until this I should be able to get through via angular right? I straightaway get the unauthorized page :(

Can someone please help me out here as to what I am missing? This is driving me nuts.

EDIT: N/W dev tools screenie
[image]

WEB-INF folder screenie
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You have to create the folder with the name `static` and paste the file within the dist folder inside it. For `type=Unauthorized, status=401` can you check the console and network tab within Developer tools

Comment: Yup, I did create a folder named static and then only pasted my dist contents into that. Also console and network tab show nothing, just the 401. If my LoginController is @CrossOrigin, I should at least see the login page, even that is not getting displayed

Comment: And further more, I checked the WEB-INF folder in tomcat, under classes it has the static folder with all my dist contents. I did do everything manually, so I verified when I moved stuff

Comment: what endpoints you can see in-network tab when you hit `http://localhost:8082/audittool` can you share the image and any logs from spring boot application?

Comment: Edited the question with screen shot for both n/w and folder containing static. And as for logs, I am very sorry but since this is a WIP project, I have not implemented any logging. If you think that would help I can do some and deploy again. Sorry about that :(

Comment: Can you post your full web configuration from Spring Boot? There might be issue with your angular route vs spring path.

Comment: @Rana_S Are you referring to my SecurityConfig?

Comment: Yes! Are you deploying your angular app as part of war?

Comment: Edited the question with full SecurityConfig.java and yes, I am going with a single war solution containing both angular and spring boot

Comment: Do you have ```resourceHandlers/viewControllers``` added anywhere? When you deploy Angular app with Spring boot, you need to configure those since you need to handle angular routes.

Comment: Nope, can you please point me to some resources/guides on the same. Could that be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you take a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46854105/4355748